# show entire dimension tree on the same page of google analytics report

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I want to create a google analytics report breakdown that will show a breakdown of the number of users for each landing page. I tried to set sessions as a metric and landing page plus country as the dimensions in the drilldown.
but the report lists 1 column for the landing page and another for the number of sessions.
 to see the countries for a specific landing page i have to click on the landing page link.

how can i view the entire dimension drill-down tree on the same page?

Comment: You can do a custom report as a "flat table" which allows you to use at max two dimensions side by side (nor further breakdown possible). Other than that you can't, really.

Comment: yes i tried the flat table. but it lists each country for each of the landing page sessions individualy. i need a total number of sessions per landing page and a bereakdown with number of visits or sessions per country as a tree.